# extern variable - why?

Tags: c, extern

I've heard that you shouldn't define anything in header files, because of the possibility of multiple defines, but if you have include guards, this shouldn't happen, right? What other reasons are there for adding extern to variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Include guards merely prevent multiple inclusion of a header within a single [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (aka *compilation unit*). This does not address the problem of multiple definitions from separate translation units at link time. Hence you should only ever put *declarations* in header (.h) files, and *definitions* in source (.c) files.

Answer (score 1):

You generally declare `extern` variables in header files when the variable is defined in one source file (more specifically, one *translation unit*), and referenced in another.